# How to print tracing output in tests?

Tags: testing, logging, rust, rust-tracing

My application is using the `tracing` Rust crate to create log output. How do I print these log messages when I'm running my tests?

Comment: No. This is about redirecting log messages to std out, not hiding of std out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`tracing_test` Rust crate](https://docs.rs/tracing-test/latest/tracing_test/) for this. It works like this:

```rust
#[traced_test]
#[test]
fn plain_old_test() {
   ...
}
```

All you have to do is add the `tracing_test` to your list of dependencies and decorate your tests with the `#[traced_test]` macro.

This also works with `tokio_macros` tests, that are decorated with `#[tokio::test]`.

Then, as @Yuri mentions, you need to run the tests with the `--nocapture` argument: `cargo t --nocapture`. This is only relevant if the test succeeds.

Comment: It is important to note here that traced_test saves all log output to ram.
I was confused why my tests, whose application produces lots of very verbose logs for debugging, was constantly increasing in memory usage to the point of getting OOM killed.

Answer (score 3):

Usually, if you need to print the output inside the tests you use `--nocapture` flag with the `cargo test` command:

```bash
$ cargo test -- --nocapture
```

Can you test if it works in your case?

Comment: Good point. Thanks!

Comment: You still need to redirect log messages to Stout though.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [test-log](https://crates.io/crates/test-log) crate. It works by overriding the `#[test]` attribute macro, allowing you to include tracing logs seamlessly into your test runs. This means you can see the log output without the need to modify each individual test. Unlike some alternative crates, which may require adding extra lines of code to **each test**, which is equivalent to calling a self-defined singleton for the tracing init in each test.

Comment: Haven't tried this but it sounds superior to my solution that requires you to add the attribute `#[traced_test]` to each test.